# Function with call to FireStore always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a function to check if a doc exists in my FireStore database, given an id. The problem is my `fire_PatronExists` function always return `undefined`.

```
const patronsRef = db.collection("patrons");

alert(fire_PatronExists(user.uid));

function fire_PatronExists(id) {

    patronsRef.doc(id).get().then(function(doc) {
        // return doc.exists();
        if (doc){return true}else {return false}
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried (doc.exists()) instead of (doc), but I get the error "doc.exists is not a function"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that your function returns undefined is totally normal: `get()` is an asynchronous method, so the return you put inside the `then` will not be executed inside `fire_PatronExists`; it will be executed a bit later. There is a [great SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean) that explains the difference between synchronous and asynchronous execution.

There are different solutions, depending on the version of JavaScript you are using. One that will work for sure is passing a callback function to `fire_PatronExists` and pass the result to that function.

This would look like that (not tested):

```
const patronsRef = db.collection("patrons");

fire_PatronExists(user.uid, function(exists) {
    alert(exists);
});

// Remember though, if you put code here, it will be executed in parallel
// with the code you put inside your callback. 

function fire_PatronExists(id, callback) {

    patronsRef.doc(id).get().then(function(doc) {

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

Using callbacks can get really messy though. If you are using a recent version of JavaScript, you might want to [read about](https://www.google.ca/search?dcr=0&source=hp&ei=PEHJWtn2D8z2zgLI9I3QDg&q=javascript%20async%20await&oq=javascript%20async%20await&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203k1l10.741.2746.0.2838.24.18.0.0.0.0.241.2981.0j12j5.17.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..7.17.2978.0..0j35i39k1j0i131k1.0.XmASK9tqTsY) the `async` and `await` keywords, they can improve your code readability a lot.